# How to check and replace array if array value exists in another multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays and I want to compare array based on `day_of_week` and `status` value.

If `day_of_week` is existing in another array and `status` is 1 then replace the array with matched array.

**$array1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [day_of_week] => sun
            [description] => sun test description
            [status] => 0
            [date] => 2019-01-11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [day_of_week] => mon
            [description] => mon test description
            [status] => 0
            [date] => 2019-01-11
        )
)
```

**$array2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [day_of_week] => mon
            [description] => mon updated test description
            [status] => 1
            [date] => 2019-01-11
        )
)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [day_of_week] => sun
            [description] => sun test description
            [status] => 0
            [date] => 2019-01-11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [day_of_week] => mon
            [description] => mon updated test description
            [status] => 1
            [date] => 2019-01-11
        )
)
```

I have tried with `array_intersect` function but not found solution to compare value based on `day_of_week` and `status`. Can anyone please help me?

```
$array = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: can every `day of the week` be present in arrays only once?

Comment: Yes. `day_of_week` will be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As day of week is unique in the arrays, you can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to index both arrays by this and the use [`array_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) to replace the data from the second array into the first array.

Also (thanks to splash58) you need filter the second array to only leave ones with status = 1...

```
$array2 = array_filter($array2, function($entry) { return $entry['status'] == '1'; });
$array1 = array_column($array1, null, "day_of_week");
$array2 = array_column($array2, null, "day_of_week");
$array1 = array_replace($array1, $array2);

print_r(array_values($array1));
```

using `array_values()` at the end removes the index in case you don't need it.

Comment: You don't check a status item with such approach

Answer (score 2):

It seems can be done by a loop

```
$array2 = array_column($array2, null, 'day_of_week');
foreach ($array1 as $k=>$x) {
  if (isset($array2[$x['day_of_week']]) and $array2[$x['day_of_week']]['status'] == 1) {
      $array1[$k] = $array2[$x['day_of_week']];
  }
}
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/63ee90f5c379f81ed7b28915a29e92f9209a44e8)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to process each element of `$array1` and check if it's corresponding entry in `$array2` (located using [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) on the `day_of_week` column) has `status == 1`. If so, return the element from `$array2`, otherwise keep the value from `$array1`:

```
$array1 = array_map(function ($v) use ($array2) {
    if (($k = array_search($v['day_of_week'], array_column($array2, 'day_of_week'))) !== false && $array2[$k]['status'] == 1)
        return $array2[$k];
    else
        return $v;
}, $array1);
print_r($array1);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 4 [day_of_week] => sun [description] => suntestdescription [status] => 0 [date] => 2019-01-11 )
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [day_of_week] => mon [description] => monupdatedtestdescription [status] => 1 [date] => 2019-01-11 ) 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vSP5s)